# Get all entries for a specific json tag only in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a database with a json field which has multiple parts including one called `tags`, there are other entries as below but I want to return only the fields with `"{"tags":{"+good":true}}"`.

```
"{"tags":{"+good":true}}"
"{"has_temps":false,"tags":{"+good":true}}"
"{"tags":{"+good":true}}"
"{"has_temps":false,"too_long":true,"too_long_as_of":"2016-02-12T12:28:28.238+00:00","tags":{"+good":true}}"
```

I can get part of the way there with this statement in my `where` clause `trips.metadata->'tags'->>'+good' = 'true'` but that returns all instances where tags are good and true including all entries above. I want to return entries with the specific statement  `"{"tags":{"+good":true}}"` only. So taking out the two entries that begin `has_temps`.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: is it 9.5 or 9.4?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jsonb` column the solution is obvious:

```
with trips(metadata) as (
values
    ('{"tags":{"+good":true}}'::jsonb),
    ('{"has_temps":false,"tags":{"+good":true}}'),
    ('{"tags":{"+good":true}}'),
    ('{"has_temps":false,"too_long":true,"too_long_as_of":"2016-02-12T12:28:28.238+00:00","tags":{"+good":true}}')
)
select *
from trips
where metadata = '{"tags":{"+good":true}}';

        metadata         
-------------------------
 {"tags":{"+good":true}}
 {"tags":{"+good":true}}
(2 rows)
```

If the column's type is `json` then you should cast it to `jsonb`:

```
...
where metadata::jsonb = '{"tags":{"+good":true}}';
```

Comment: Magic thanks!!! it was the casting the data as jsonb I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you can check text value of the "tags" key, like here:

```
select true 
where '{"has_temps":false,"too_long":true,"too_long_as_of":"2016-02-12T12:28:28.238+00:00","tags":{"+good":true}}'::json->>'tags'
= '{"+good":true}'
```